# In PhpStorm, avoid specifing for each test its working directory

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I run my test using the **PHPStorm PHPUnit runner**, I need to set for each test its "custom working directory" to my project root (eg: /home/remmel/ws/Symfony) otherwise, I cannot open the file aside that test (**failed to open stream**: No such file or directory).

When running the **phpunit** command in *Symfony* directory everything **works fine**.

Is that possible to set that working directory for all the tests?

```
/home/remmel/ws/Symfony/tests/AppBundle/
- OneTest.php
- afile.xml


class OneTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $f = "tests/AppBundle/afile.xml";

    public function testA(){

        getcwd(); //if phpstorm return  /home/remmel/ws/Symfony/tests/AppBundle
        //if phpunit command return /home/remmel/ws/Symfony

        file_get_contents($this->f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well ... you can edit `PHPUnit` Run/Debug Configuration entry that is located under `Defaults` branch and specify `Custom working directory` there. Now any new PHPUnit Run/Debug Configuration that will be created from now (in this project) will have that field predefined with that value. Unfortunately you will have to edit any existing configurations manually.

Comment: Another alternative -- use bootstrap file and correct the path there (change it to a desired one) -- if path contains `tests` the change current folder to the path above it -- may work (at least worth checking out).